# Need to correct mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE student
        INNER JOIN
    fee_head2 ON (student.new_old = fee_head2.new_old)
        INNER JOIN
    fee_head2 ON (student.class = fee_head2.class) 
SET 
    student.head1_apr = fee_head2.head1_apr
```

This is showing #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'fee_head2'.

Can anyone correct this query for me?

Comment: try using table alias

Comment: i am new can you please suggest

Comment: but you reiterate a inner join ... this is the problem!

Comment: eg: INNER JOIN fee_head2 AS f1 (student.new_old =
f1.new_old)

Comment: The error says it all: the table 'fee_head2' in your result is not unique. That's evident, as it's in there twice. When you were suggested using a table alias, you could at least have googled what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to JOIN the same table again, try this:

```
UPDATE student INNER JOIN fee_head2 
ON (student.new_old = fee_head2.new_old) 
AND (student.class = fee_head2.class) 
SET student.head1_apr = fee_head2.head1_apr
```

Answer (score 0):

Aziz beat me to the obvious naswer.

```
UPDATE student SET student.head1_apr = 
CASE 
     WHEN student.new_old = fee_head2.new_old AND student.class = fee_head2.class THEN fee_head2.head1_apr
    ELSE NULL
END
```